# MultipartEntity image upload not working

Tags: android

I want to upload image using MultipartEntity  , I have added all external jar files.

But when I try to use below code I get class not found error , and image is not able to upload.

Now I restart eclipse , Now I get error like

**Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;**

**Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;**

Below is my php file and java code.

```
<?php
$photo = $_FILES['photo']['name'];


    if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name']))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "User_files/".$_FILES['photo']['name']);
    }

?>
```

.

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/a.png");

        //Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: setting up multipart entity");

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        //Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: file length = " + file.length());
        //Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: file exist = " + file.exists());

        mpEntity.addPart("photo", new FileBody(file, "image/png"));
        //mpEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody("1"));
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I got error class not found , But I add all jar files in lib folder

Comment: Witch class is not found? Which jar files did you add?

Comment: I solved this one , look at here now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975577/multipartentity-image-is-not-upload